# `apt-get update --dry-run` command does not work anymore

Tags: debian, apt

On older systems, the command `apt-get update --dry-run` did work and was very useful to check if the real command will work.

With newer versions, we have :

```
$ apt-get update --dry-run
E: Command line option --dry-run is not understood in combination with the other options
```

Is there an alternative ?

Note : if someone dares to ask "why would you want to do that ?", I'll answer "why is it not possible anymore ?" ! :)

Comment: What's wrong with running `apt-get update` directly? It's not a command that would wreck something.

Comment: The dry-run is supposed to be run by our monitoring system, so it's weird to have monitoring probes actually "doing things" on all servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the behaviour of `apt-get update --dry-run` on a wheezy system. If I remove one of the list files from /var/lib/apt/lists `apt-get update --dry-run` downloads the missing file.

This suggests to me that `apt-get update --dry-run` does the same thing as simply `apt-get update`.

The `--dry-run` option is probably no longer valid because it was confusing people into believing that it wasn't modifying the system, when in fact evidence suggests that it was.

Comment: That's a good point. I indeed was thinking that the dry-run was real. So ok, I'll keep in mind that there is (and was) no way to simulate an "apt-get update". Thanks for your answer !

Comment: It could be useful to add to this answer whether an actual dry-run mode currently exists or not. Just saying.